# Macro for counting number of elements in an array

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

We all know the classic version of counting the number of elements in a C array: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)`

But this is dangerous, because if used on a pointer it will return garbage values.

So I made this macro, utilizing gcc extensions. As far as I can tell, it works the way it is supposed to, which is causing compiler error when used on a pointer instead of array.

```
#define COUNT(a) (__builtin_choose_expr( \
                  __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(&a[0])), \
                  (void)0, \
                  (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))))
```

```
/* Only to demonstrate how to use the macro. It's not part of the code
   I want reviewed. */
int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int *p;
    int x = COUNT(arr);

    // This line will yield the compiler error:
    //     error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    int y = COUNT(p);
}
```

Any suggestions? Have I missed anything crucial?

Comment: klutt, Why `int x` and not `size_t x`, the type returned by the division?

Comment: See also [Array-size macro that rejects pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452971/2410359).

Comment: Why are you trying to write the value of a `void` on the last line of your `main`? What are you trying to illustrate here?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica See comment. Also, I should have realized that a linux kernel developer already thought of this :)

Comment: @Mast Because that will fail. I want a compiler error if it is used on a pointer instead of an array.

Comment: @klutt Ah, you're showing intended failure here. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

We need to protect `a` when it's an expression - we've put parens around `a[0]` where we should have put them around `a`:

```
(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a)[0])
```

For the same reason, I think that the second `typeof` should be

```
typeof(&(a)[0])
```

I have to admit that I can't easily contrive an expression of array type where the parens make a difference, but better safe than sorry...